# Simple drag and drop with sorting without external library

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop

I want to implement drag and drop of elements with sorting and I don't want to use any external library.

There will be 2 containers, I want to sort the elements within a container and drag/drop between the two containers. Any suggestions?

I've tried HTML5 and other things but didn't worked

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you can drag and drop a component the other component and then when you add this component in an array you can sort between other components in this array. Will that work for you? Or I didn't understand you correctly?

Comment: yes you understood correctly

Answer (score 0):

[image]

In the above screen shot, I want to drag and drop the elements from shown to hidden and vice-versa, also sorting the elements among "Shown" row

Answer (score 0):

You can assign `onDrop` and `onDrag` events to div. You can hold each component in an array and when you drag you can remove the item from and array and when you drop, you can add this item to array. After that you can sort the array by `array.sort()`

```
<div onDrag={this.handleDrag()} onDrop={thishandleDrop()}>

handleDrag = () => {
    //remove your item in array here
}

handleDrag = () => {
        //add your item to array here
    }
```

Comment: any examples? I have a dynamic data coming from props which I've assigned to state, so index is also required while sorting

Answer (score 0):

```js
/**
 * Displays Dialog for Table show/hide columns
 * @default {string} submitLabel, cancelLabel
 * @default {bool} open
 * @default {array} suggestions
 */

import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import SettingsIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Settings";
import IconButton from "@material-ui/core/IconButton";
import { theme } from "../../../../utilities/theme-default";
import HLTooltip from "../../../atoms/ToolTip";
import HLDialog from "../../../grouped/Dialog";
import HLSaveSettings from "../SaveTableSettings";
import HLTypography from "../../../atoms/Typography";
import HLChip from "@material-ui/core/Chip";
import * as colors from "../../../../utilities/color";
import Draggable from "react-draggable";

export const styles = () => ({
  tableAction: {
    width: "100%",
    marginTop: `${theme.spacing.unit}px`
  },
  container: {
    display: "flex"
  },
  title: {
    flex: "0 0 auto"
  },
  section: {
    border: `1px solid ${colors.neutralDark["120"]}`,
    marginTop: `${theme.spacing.unit * 3}px`,
    padding: `${theme.spacing.unit}px 0 ${theme.spacing.unit * 3}px ${theme
      .spacing.unit * 6}px`,
    display: "flex"
  },
  chipTextStyle: {
    marginTop: `${theme.spacing.unit * 4}px`
  },
  chipStyle: {
    padding: `${theme.spacing.unit * 3}px`,
    marginTop: `${theme.spacing.unit}px`
  },
  dialogStyle: {
    width: "500px"
  },
  defaultSection: {
    marginTop: `${theme.spacing.unit * 2}px`
  }
});

/**
 * state component which handles table show/hide columns
 */
export class HLShowHide extends React.Component {
  state = {
    open: false,
    headers: this.props.headers
  };

  /**
   * function to display dialog for show/hide opetations
   */
  dialogToggle = () => {
    this.setState({
      open: !this.state.open
    });
  };

  onStart() {
    this.setState({ activeDrags: this.state.activeDrags + 1 });
  }

  onStop() {
    this.setState({ activeDrags: this.state.activeDrags - 1 });
  }

  onDragStart = (e, sectionIndex, index) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    this.draggedItem = this.state.headers.sections[sectionIndex].items[index];
    this.dragItemSection = sectionIndex;
    this.dragItemIndex = index;
    e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = "move";
    e.dataTransfer.setData("text/html", e.target.parentNode);
    e.dataTransfer.setDragImage(e.target.parentNode, 20, 20);
  };

  onDragOver = (sectionIndex, index) => {
    const draggedOverItem = this.state.headers.sections[sectionIndex].items[
      index
    ];

    // if the item is dragged over itself, ignore
    if (this.draggedItem === draggedOverItem) {
      return;
    }
    if (this.dragItemSection !== sectionIndex) {
      var otherItems = this.state.headers.sections[this.dragItemSection].items;
      otherItems.splice(this.dragItemIndex, 1);
    }
    // filter out the currently dragged item
    let items = this.state.headers.sections[sectionIndex].items.filter(
      item => item !== this.draggedItem
    );

    // add the dragged item after the dragged over item
    items.splice(index, 0, this.draggedItem);
    const sections = this.state.headers.sections;
    sections[sectionIndex].items = items;
    sections[this.dragItemSection].items = otherItems;
    this.setState({ headers: { ...this.state.headers, sections } });
  };

  onDragOverSection = sectionIndex => {
    if (this.state.headers.sections[sectionIndex].length === 0) {
      var otherItems = this.state.headers.sections[this.dragItemSection].items;
      otherItems.splice(this.dragItemIndex, 1);
      let items = this.state.headers.sections[sectionIndex].items;
      items.push(this.draggedItem);
      const sections = this.state.headers.sections;
      sections[this.dragItemSection].items = otherItems;
      sections[sectionIndex].items = items;
      this.setState({ headers: { ...this.state.headers, sections } });
    }
  };

  onDragEnd = () => {
    this.draggedIdx = null;
  };

  render() {
    const { classes, submitLabel, cancelLabel } = this.props;
    const { open, headers } = this.state;
    const dragHandlers = {
      onStart: this.onStart.bind(this),
      onStop: this.onStop.bind(this)
    };

    const dialogBody = (
      <div className={classes.dialogStyle}>
        {headers.sections.map((section, sectionIndex) => (
          <div className={classes.section}>
            <span className={classes.chipTextStyle}>
              <HLTypography
                variant={
                  theme.palette.tableConstant.showHideColumn.sections.variant
                }
                color={
                  theme.palette.tableConstant.showHideColumn.sections.color
                }
              >
                {section.label}
              </HLTypography>
            </span>
            <span onDragOver={() => this.onDragOverSection(sectionIndex)}>
              {section.items.map((item, itemIndex) => (
                <div
                  className={classes.chipStyle}
                  key={item.value}
                  data-id={`${itemIndex}_${sectionIndex}`}
                  onDragOver={() => this.onDragOver(sectionIndex, itemIndex)}
                >
                  <Draggable
                    onDrag={this.handleDrag.bind(this)}
                    {...dragHandlers}
                  >
                    <HLChip label={item.label} />
                  </Draggable>
                </div>
              ))}
            </span>
          </div>
        ))}
        <div className={classes.defaultSection}>
          <HLSaveSettings
            defaultLabel={headers.defaultLabel}
            isDefault={headers.isDefault}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        {open && (
          <div className={classes.container}>
            <div className={classes.tableAction}>
              <HLDialog
                open={open}
                submitLabel={submitLabel}
                cancelLabel={cancelLabel}
                bodyText={dialogBody}
                maxWidth="xl"
                onSubmit={() => {}}
                onCancel={() => {
                  this.dialogToggle();
                }}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        )}
        {!open && (
          <React.Fragment>
            <HLTooltip title="Settings" placement="top">
              <IconButton aria-label="Settings">
                <SettingsIcon onClick={this.dialogToggle} />
              </IconButton>
            </HLTooltip>
          </React.Fragment>
        )}
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

HLShowHide.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object,
  headers: PropTypes.arrayOf().isRequired,
  open: PropTypes.bool,
  submitLabel: PropTypes.string,
  cancelLabel: PropTypes.string
};

HLShowHide.defaultProps = {
  open: false,
  submitLabel: "Set",
  cancelLabel: "Cancel"
};

export default withStyles(styles)(HLShowHide);
```

my code which I tried